# Get session value in parameterless constructor in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a class with a parameterless constructor and I am wondering how to get a value from the session. I have tried dependency injection but since I am using this class for deserialization, the httpcontextaccessor is always null.

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        _language = "french"; <-- how to get value from session
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name { 
        get {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_language))
                {
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    this.localization.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TryGetValue(_language, out dict));
                    return dict != null && dict.ContainsKey("name") ? dict["name"] : _Name;
                }
                else
                    return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> localization { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A session denotes server side state which is something you should try to avoid if possible. Looking at your code it seems like are interested in a language code (Maybe an ISO language code like "en"). I would recommend you put this in a cookie or submit it with the http request  from the client explicitly. The client could persist it either in a cookie or in the local or session storage.

Comment: On a side note I would strongly recommend you use the ISO code for any cultures / countries you are using in your application. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes. Your application could use a lookup to get the corresponding name for a culture code if required (there are plenty of existing libraries available to do this in npmjs).

Answer (score 0):

You can get session value in custom model like below:

```
public class Category
{
    private readonly ISession _session;    //add this..
    public Category(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
        _language = _session.GetString("language");
    }

    private string? _language;
    private string _Name;
    public string Name { 
        get {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_language))
                {
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    this.localization.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TryGetValue(_language, out dict));
                    return dict != null && dict.ContainsKey("name") ? dict["name"] : _Name;
                }
                else
                    return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> localization { get; set; }

}
```

Test it in Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("language", "en-US");
    var model = new CategoryModel(HttpContext.Session);

    return View();
}
```

Be sure add `AddSession` and `UseSession` middleware in Program.cs or in Startup.cs.

Reference: [Configure session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-session-state)

---

> but since I am using this class for deserialization, the httpcontextaccessor is always null.

A simple demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    public CategoryModel(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        _language = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("language");
    }
    //........
}
```

Test in Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("language", "en-US");
        var model = new CategoryModel(_contextAccessor);

        return View();
    }
}
```

Register the service like:

```
//.....
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is what I tried first, but the injection in the Category constructor are always null when I do jObject.ToObject<IEnumerable<Category>>() so it wouldn't work for me. I ended up doing a static utility class which is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a static class:

```
public static class AppContext
{
    public static IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }
    public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        HttpContextAccessor = accessor;
    }
}
```

And then in the class where I couldn't do dependency injection, I was able to get the session:

```
    public Category()
    {
        _language = AppContext.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("language");
    }
```

Had to add this to Configure in Startup:

```
AppContext.Configure(context);
```